# Google widget got disappeared each time after reboot

Tags: launcher, google-now, lineageos

I am using Google Now launcher as default launcher on my Lineage 14.1,Redmi 1s. After installing a nightly, or after reboot, I can see that Google widget is got disappeared. I cannot see any widget(4x1 sized google widget) in widget settings. I have set home screen with some app shortcuts. To replace Google widget, I need to clear Google app content. It resets, home screen app shortcuts and clears Google data. Any solution?